# JS код для перехода от выбранных label в fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть fieldset с label в внутри. Задача стоит такая, при выборе label и нажатия на button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-answer="success" data-nbid="#B21_1" data-save>Далее</button>
```

происходит переход к cscn:block с именем указанный в data-nbid.

пример fieldset :

```
<fieldset class="quest-variants required " data-thmid="33328"><br>
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="b20-1"> 1. Абсолют Банк</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="b20-2"> 2. Альфа-Банк</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="b20-3"> 3. Возрождение</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="b20-4"> 4. Восточный банк </label><br>
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="b20-5"> 5. Газпромбанк</label><br>
</fieldset ><br>
```

Проблема в том, что если выбраны например 1, 2 и 5 label должен переходить к cscn:block с именем name="B21_1", name="B21_2" и name="B21_5" по порядку.
Если список не большой переходы легко сделать руками, а если список 28 строк то это уже гораздо сложнее.
код перехода к cscn:block name="B21_5":

```
$('#B20-block input').change(function() {
    if($('#B20-block input[value="5"]').is(':checked')
    $('#B20-block .answer-toolbar button').data('nbid','#B21_5-block');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить значение выбранного чека и подставить в нужное место (номер блока)

```js
$('#B20-block input').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    $('#B20-block .answer-toolbar button').data('nbid','#B21_' + $(this).val() + '-block');
});
```